# Count items inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am using this code to fetch 100 trending public repos on GitHub.

For every language, I calculated the The list of repos using the language, but I can't calculate the number of repos using this language

part of my code

```
const api_url =
    "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>30&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=100";
  const response = await fetch(api_url);
  const data = await response.json();

  var urls = data.items
      .map((a) => ({
        language: a.language,
        url: a.url,
      }))
      .filter((el) => {
        return el.language != null;
      }),
    result = urls.reduce((r, { language, url }) => {
      match = r.find((item) => language in item);
      match ? match[language].push(url) : r.push({ [language]: [url] });

      return r;
    }, []);
```

This is sample of my output

```
[{
"Vala": [
"https://api.github.com/repos/p-e-w/finalterm"
]},
{
"Swift": [
"https://api.github.com/repos/louisdh/panelkit",
"https://api.github.com/repos/hyperoslo/Whisper",
]},
{
"C": [
"https://api.github.com/repos/wishstudio/flinux",
"https://api.github.com/repos/Sunzxyong/Tiny"
]}]
```

My desired output is to count the URLs of each language
and append it to its corresponding language

Comment: Add the count where? `{ "Vala": [ "https://api.github.com/repos/p-e-w/finalterm" ], count: 1}`? You could just go through each language and get the `.length` of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes:

- reduce urls to an object because it's faster to lookup entries than array.find and generally less complex.
- take the object and generate an array with language, url list for that language, and count (which is just url list length).

```js
const urls = [
  {language: "java", url: "url1"},
  {language: "java", url: "url2"},
  {language: "php", url: "url3"},
  {language: "javascript", url:"url4"},
  {language: "php", url: "url5"},
  {language: "java", url: "url6"}
];

result = Object.entries(
  urls.reduce((r, { language, url }) => {
    if (!r[language]) r[language] = [];
    r[language].push(url);
    return r;
  }, {})
).map(([language, urls]) => (
  {language, urls, count: urls.length}
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would consist in changing your `acc` type from `[]` to `{}` that could carry a count property:

```js
const urls = [{
  language: "Javascript",
  url: "url1"
}, {
  language: "Python",
  url: "url2"
}, {
  language: "Javascript",
  url: "url3"
}]

const result = urls.reduce((r, {
  language,
  url
}) => {
  if (r[language]) {
    r[language].urls.push(url)
    r[language].count ++

  } else {
    r[language] = { urls: [url], count : 1 }
  }
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Alternatively, to avoid looping 3 times on the `items` array, you could do all your operations from `map` et `filter` within the reduce

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with `map`:

```js
    console.log([{
    "Vala": [
    "https://api.github.com/repos/p-e-w/finalterm"
    ]},
    {
    "Swift": [
    "https://api.github.com/repos/louisdh/panelkit",
    "https://api.github.com/repos/hyperoslo/Whisper",
    ]},
    {
    "C": [
    "https://api.github.com/repos/wishstudio/flinux",
    "https://api.github.com/repos/Sunzxyong/Tiny"
    ]}].map((item) => {return {[Object.keys(item)[0]]: item[Object.keys(item)[0]].length}}));
```

Answer (score 0):

simply do

```js
let output = Object.entries( data.items.reduce((res,{url,language})=>
  {
  res[language] = res[language] ?? []
  res[language].push(url)
  return res
  },{})
).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v, count: v.length}))
```